# Open 2 screens split with zsh & iterm2 via script

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh, iterm

I would like to have a script which would be able to open 1 iterm tab which contains 2 split screens inside via script.

Is it possible or should I install an additional lib for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! This is possible without any external libraries.

Using [osascript](https://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html) to 'send' commands to Iterm this simple [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script should open a new tab, split it and call some commands;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

osascript<<EOF
    tell application "iTerm"
        activate
        select first window

        # Create new tab
        tell current window
            create tab with default profile
        end tell

        # Split pane
        tell current session of current window
            split vertically with default profile
        end tell

        # Run command in Pane-1
        tell first session of current tab of current window
            write text "cd /tmp"
            write text "pwd"
        end tell

        # Run command in Pane-2
        tell second session of current tab of current window
            write text "echo Second tab!;"
        end tell
    end tell
EOF
```

[Screen recording of script (`.gif`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPSKk.gif)

Comment: Thank you, you just helped me a huge deal. Thanks...