# New iTerm tab with command from bash script

Tags: bash, automation, iterm2

I am trying to automate a few things in the morning when I get to work, like start the docker env, start the front end stuff etc...

I want to type in a terminal command that will open up a terminal tab ([iterm](/questions/tagged/iterm)) for each of these tasks.

I have managed to get the tabs to open, but I cannot figure out how to make them run commands.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
open -a iTerm . "start_docker.sh"
```

However, this just opens up a black terminal window.

*Ideally*, I would like to not also have separate script files.

Comment: I've used the "send text at start" option in iTerm2>Profiles>General>Command before for a similar task; e.g. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115598/how-to-set-an-iterm2-startup-command

Comment: Hi @jared_mamrot Thanks for the suggestion. I dont want every terminal window to run those commands. I plan to use an alias. I dont think your suggestions allows for only specific windows instead of all, unless i'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, I created a profile called "hotkey" that ran a set of commands and used a hotkey (fn+F2) to launch a terminal window with that profile. When I opened a normal terminal window the commands didn't run. I don't know whether you can open multiple terminal windows with a specific profile, but you might be able to tweak this to suit your use case. (I used https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48796/iterm-as-a-slide-out-terminal-from-the-top-of-the-screen to configure the hotkey terminal window)

Comment: This can be done with the iTerm Python API. Create a Python script that will spawn all the tabs with the desired commands, then call the Python script in the morning.

Comment: Or if you're on Mac, you can do something like this: [Open 2 screens split with zsh & iterm2 via script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951674/open-2-screens-split-with-zsh-iterm2-via-script/64319022#64319022) witch uses osascript instead off the Python api.